# File permissions on a web server?

Tags: permissions, upload, web, chmod

I'm new at writing code for websites. The website allows users to upload files, such as profile pictures or other pictures. The files are saved in the unix file system and the URLs to find those images are stored in a MySQL database.

It seems like the only way I can let the user upload files is to give write access to anybody using chmod. Otherwise it complains that it doesn't have write permissions. But they shouldn't be able to write whatever they want or overwrite other users stuff. Similarly, to allow users to see images that they have rightful access to, they need read permissions on the file system. But now that means that anybody with the url to that picture can see the image too, correct? That's not what I want.

Is there a solution to this contradiction? Or am I thinking about the problem incorrectly? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the permissions in your application and not expose arbitrary parts of your local filesystem directly to the clients.  Your *application* should decide what files someone can see or where to write data.  You should not trust data (filenames, etc) from your clients...ideally, store files on disk using systematically generated names and store human-readable names in the database.

Answer (score 0):

SunStar9,

Since you are already using a MySQL database to store the URL of the image on the file system, why not just store the image itself as a BLOB (binary large object)?

This is generally a well-accepted design practice for allowing users to upload binary data to a website.

Are you using PHP, Java, Ruby/Rails, or something other to develop your website?  Depending on what you are using, there could be file upload/management plugins or modules that will help you develop what you are trying to do if you are certain you want to use the files ystem for storing the image data.